# Child selection using JQuery

Tags: jquery, select, children

I have the following code

```
<div id="gridRow"></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLA</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLB</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLC</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLD</span></div></div>
</div>
```

This is the header section of a CSS3 table. I'm implementing a mouseover function which displays (ROW_TITLE, COL_TITLE).

I need, here, just a check on the code snippet that I'm using to get, for *columnID=2*, the *title=COLB*

```
var columnID = 2;
$colNameDiv = $("#gridRow div:nth-child(" + columnID + ") div span");
console.log($colNameDiv.text());
```

Where is the mistake?

Riccardo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a closing `</div>` tag *immediately* after opening the `#gridRow` div, which means the `.gridX` elements are not children of that div. If you remove the extra closing tag it works fine:

```
<div id="gridRow">
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLA</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLB</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLC</span></div></div>
   <div class="gridC-R45"><div><span>COLD</span></div></div>
</div>
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aQdP2/1/)

Assuming you aren't already I would suggest using a text editor with syntax highlighting. It makes it 99.9% impossible to make mistakes like this.

Comment: The funny think is, I tried his source code on jsfiddle and it did work.

Comment: @reporter that's odd, it doesn't in my fiddle.

Comment: You are right. It was a really stupid mistake. My eclipse is dead and I'm trying using a notepad.... Thanks!

Comment: @KingKing try it out if you don't trust me. You can edit Rory's example if you want (you dont have to press the update button)

Comment: @reporter please don't waste my time. Already tested it on Opera and Maxthon http://jsfiddle.net/K42yU/ There is no reason it could work. It's so obvious. If it worked that's a so **terrible** bug in the broweser. BTW, what kind of **buggy** browser you tested on?

Comment: Hmm, ok it was mistake of mine. Sorry. I mixed up the the consolo command with panels output. Obviously I working already too long.